# Maximum distance of and uncolored vertex from any of the colored vertices | Optimal Solution

Tags: graph, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

**Problem**

There are n locations ( vertices ) in a city, which are connected through streets of length 1 ( edge length = 1 ). Some of the locations have petrol stations ( colored vertex ) while others don't. People at locations with no petrol stations, go to their closest petrol station. What is the maximum distance one may have to travel to find a petrol station?

**My solution**

I have been able to come up with a BFS approach, where I initialize the maximum distance for the non-petrol location to max_int, then I do a BFS from every petrol location and keep updating the distances of the non-petrol location.
However, I feel like there must be a more optimal solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOOP N over uncolored vertices
    SET D(N) = MAX INT
LOOP N over uncolored vertices
    BFS from N DO FOR each V reached
        IF V is colored 
            STOP BFS ( no need to search further )
        ELSE IF N-V distance less than D(N)
            D(V) = N-V distance
SET M = 0
LOOP N over uncolored vertices
   IF D(N) > M
      M = D(N)
OUTPUT M
```